# How can I model a flyback transformer on PSPICE / Multisim?

Tags: transformer, flyback, pspice

I need to simulate a **flyback transformer**, [this one specifically](http://katalog.we-online.com/en/pbs/WE-UOST?sid=338568f8d9). I have not used any models not provided in the regular PSPICE or Multisim before. I checked the manufacturer website and no models were provided (besides some for 3D models).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Link to one specific one is my advice.

Comment: http://katalog.we-online.com/pbs/datasheet/760871543.pdf

Comment: Hmmm... not quite enough to go on in the data sheet I feel. They state leakage inductance and DC resistances but it's a bit lacking in other areas. I can tell it's a flyback device and it's power rating is up to 16 watts from the data sheet but individual leakage inductances and capacitances are sadly lacking. Have you tried Premier Magnetics as previously mentioned?